# How to construct a nested box plot in Seaborn from three dataframes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have three datasets, and I am now making 3 different box plots. Right now I am using:

```
chart1 = sns.catplot(x="Provider", y="Appearances", kind="box", data=mlt_sample1k)
chart2 = sns.catplot(x="Provider", y="Appearances", kind="box", data=mlt_sample10k)
chart3 = sns.catplot(x="Provider", y="Appearances", kind="box", data=mlt_sample100k)
```

where `mlt_sample1k`, `mlt_sample10k` and `mlt_sample100k` are my three dataframes.

I want to combine these into a single boxplot, with 3 parallel boxes per provider, as in the example [from the docs.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot) Something like:

[image]

but with 3 boxes, and the Thu, Fri, etc would be my "provider" categories. I see that in the docs they simply use:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",

                 data=tips, palette="Set3")
```

However this does not work for me, as I have to specify three datasets, one for each box. How can I do this?

EDIT:  The structure of my dataframes is always the same:

```
item  |  provider  | appearances

'dog'    'prov1'      0.001
'cat'    'prov2'      0.02
'pig'    'prov1'      0.03
...
```

The box plots represent the statistics of the items, according to the appearances column, per each provider (6 in total) per each dataframe.

The three dataframes are NOT the same length.

Comment: More information on the dfs structure would be useful. Have you tried creating an axis object and passing this to each individual call of boxplot?

Comment: @FChm I have edited my answer with the dataframe structures. As for your suggestion, I am not sure what you mean. Could you try and paste a small code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could `concat` the three dataframes and `assign` a column to be used as the hue like:

```
sns.catplot(x="Provider", y="Appearances", 
            kind="box", hue='h',
            data=pd.concat([mlt_sample1k.assign(h='1k'), 
                            mlt_sample10k.assign(h='10k'), 
                            mlt_sample100k.assign(h='100k')])
           )
```